# The method getStatusLine() is undefined for the type HttpClient

Tags: java, android

I have been using HttpClient to connect android with Django. Now i need to find out the response code . I tired the following

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/ecp/profile/?format=json";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
httpget.setHeader("AUTHORIZATION", un.getText().toString()+":"+hash);
client.execute(httpget);
int code = client.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

but it throws following error

```
The method getStatusLine() is undefined for the type HttpClient
```

Any idea what to do?
Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do it on response not client

```
HttpResponse respone=client.execute(httpget);

 int athul=respone.getStatusLine().getStatusCode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.May be it will be helpful for you.

```
final HttpResponse res = httpClient.execute(httpget);

    final String code = res.getStatusLine().toString();
```